# MATLAB fopen to open a file which doesn't have a file extension

Tags: matlab, fopen

I have a file called `lol` on `C:\`. So when I run `fopen('C:\lol','a');` to open the file, MATLAB can't open it. I think it's looking for a `.txt` or `.m` file extension.

How do I open this file in append mode as I want to append data to the file?

Comment: The problem is not the extension. I just tried `file = open('lol','a');` on a freshly created file and it worked fine (using R2010a on OS X). Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes i get the fid as -1 . 
Error using ==> fwrite
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to
generate a valid file identifier.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7. Does it make any difference? And I am running matlab R 2011 A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have UAC (user access control) to create/modify files in `C:\`. Try some "safe" location like your Desktop.

Comment: I have run matlab as administrator. On the same C drive i can fopen a file called "good.txt".

Comment: @Zer0: Check if you can open the file to read: `fid = fopen('c:\lol','r');` If yes, then @Jacob is exactly right.

Comment: @Zer0 I'm running Windows 7 with Matlab 2011B and I get fid of -1 when not running as administrator but a valid fid when running as administrator. With Windows 7 only an Administrator can write to files in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on file extensions.  Why can't you just change the format of the file to a .txt or whatever format you want.